# How to scrape data which have auto-scroll and lazy loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, ruby-on-rails-5, nokogiri

I want to scrape some data from a website. (I am using Rails and Nokogiri.)
The site which I want to scrape is having lazy loading with a scroll event. But I have a problem with the url of ajax request.

The site uses a complex request : `load_more?id=1837373&lastPostid=987984545` instead of a regular request like `?page=1`.

Is it possible to scroll down 2 times and fetch all data?

Thoughts?

Comment: Some examples of the HTML DOM ? Example: find the total count of visible elements per page, iterate them and on the latest, send scroll event ?

Comment: the xhr request is not like ?page=1 to easily iterate..